# Python `mail.Send` successful but outlook email not delivered

Tags: python, email, winapi, outlook, pywin32

I already referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63898789/vb-net-outlook-no-error-in-the-code-but-mail-is-not-sent). Don't mark it as duplicate please.

I wrote the below code to send an email via python

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
From = outlook.Session.Accounts[1]
mail.To = 'test@org.com'
mail.Subject = 'Test Email'
mail.HTMLBody = '<h3>This is HTML Body</h3>'
mail.Body = "This is the normal body"
mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, From))
mail.Send()  # successfully executed
```

The above code is successfully executed but still the email is not delivered and its been more than 15 mins. If I do it manually using outlook,am able to send and receive messages.

Can help me what is the issue here?

**update - mail.display() looks like below**

[image]

**update - mail.Send() in outbox looks like below**

[image]

**update - error for 2nd mailbox**

[image]

**update - code**

```
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
for acc in outlook.Session.Accounts:
    if acc.DisplayName == 'user2@org.com':
        print("hi")
        mail.SendUsingAccount = acc.DisplayName
mail.To = 'user1@org.com'
mail.Subject = 'Test Email'
mail.HTMLBody = '<h3>This is HTML Body</h3>'
mail.Body = "This is the normal body"
mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, mail.SendUsingAccount))
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
```

Comment: I think this one answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332577/send-outlook-email-via-python

Comment: Is there no debug message? Whether to add pythoncom.CoInitialize()?

Comment: I had `pythoncon.Colinitialize()` but it returned nothing.

Comment: Does it make a difference if Outlook is running at the time your code is executed? can you see the message in the Outbox or Sent Items folders?

Comment: Yes, i see them in outbox and it is there for more than 6 hourse

Comment: Have you tried using the `SendAndRecieve` method after calling `Send`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between Outlook and your code is the synchronization with the mail server. Outlook may cache submitted items and send them when the store is synced with the mail server.

The [NameSpace.SendAndReceive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.sendandreceive) method initiates immediate delivery of all undelivered messages submitted in the current session, and immediate receipt of mail for all accounts in the current profile. `SendAndReceive` provides the programmatic equivalent to the `Send/Receive All` command that is available when you click `Tools` and then `Send/Receive`. All accounts defined in the current profile are used in `Send/Receive All`. If an online connection is required to perform the `Send/Receive All`, the connection is made according to user preferences.

Read more about that in the [How To: Perform Send/Receive in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/05/outlook-send-receive-programmatically/) article.

Also you may try to run the following code:

```
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
for acc in outlook.Session.Accounts:
    if acc.DisplayName == 'user2@org.com':
        print("hi")
        mail.SendUsingAccount = acc.DisplayName
mail.To = 'user1@org.com'
mail.Subject = 'Test Email'
mail.HTMLBody = '<h3>This is HTML Body</h3>'
mail.Body = "This is the normal body"
mail.Send()
```

Comment: upvoted. But when i do click "send and receive" on outlook, it just doesn't synchronize and throws error as shown above.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, From))` line of code? Does it work correctly in that case?

Comment: If you don't mind, can I seek your help to write the code in your answer please? by copying my code and also including the changes that you suggested? because, when I try, it doesn't work. So, want to make sure whether am doing it correctly. would really be grateful

Comment: doing send and receive programmatically doesn't contain python (and am not sure how to do that). help please

Comment: C++ can use WinSock to implement this

Comment: WinSock is not related to the original task in any way.